# Word construction like "philanthropist" but regarding silence instead of humankind?

Tags: english, neologism

What would be the Latin/English term for somebody who loves silence? Featuring phil(e) as pre- or suffix.

Like ... silenciophile? That maybe makes "some sense" - but I've no idea if it is correct or if there would be a canonical neologism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latin freely adopted Greek words, including compounds, but in general did not freely create compounds with both Latin and Greek elements, like the modern creation "sociology", and similarly with your suggested form "silenciophile" (better "silentiophile").  If you want to create a compound with "-phile", then "hesychophile" would be better, consisting of Greek elements only.

Comment: Ah - what a blunder - asking here for a word ending with -phil(e). Is there a Latin equivalent to this suffix that could be used to construct a Latin term?